# Splitting a string in a dataframe in R using multiple literal delimiters

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have a single-column dataframe of addresses like this:

```
ADDRESS
123 Main Street Unit A
456 Main Street Apt 3
789 Main Street Floor 2
```

I would like to parse the addresses to separate the Unit/Apt/Floor information from the rest of the street address. Is there a simple way to accomplish this, knowing at the outset that the delimiters should be " Unit", " Apt", and " Floor"?

The desired end result would be a two-column dataframe that looks like this:

```
ADDRESS           UNIT
123 Main Street   Unit A
456 Main Street   Apt 3
789 Main Street   Floor 2
```

I have tried using `separate` from the `tidyr` package, but it only accepts (to my knowledge) a single delimiter argument. So it would be possible to accomplish this task with multiple calls to `separate` but this seems silly.

```
df <- df %>% tidyr::separate(ADDRESS, into = c("ADDRESS","UNIT"), sep = ' Apt')
# This would need to repeated using ' Unit' and ' Floor'.
```

Similarly, it seems that `stringr::str_split_fixed()` should be able to handle this task, but again I cannot figure out how to complete the process with a single call (i.e., specifying the three delimiters at once).

```
stringr::str_split_fixed(df$Address, c(' Unit', ' Apt', ' Floor'), 2)
# Does not work! Additionally does not result in additional column in dataframe as desired.
```

Here is code to create the sample dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)    # for piping
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(ADDRESS = c("123 Main Street Unit A", "456 Main Street Apt 3", "789 Main Street Floor 2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr::separate` you could do:

```r
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(ADDRESS = c("123 Main Street Unit A", "456 Main Street Apt 3", "789 Main Street Floor 2"))
df %>% 
  separate(ADDRESS, sep = "\\s(?=Unit|Apt|Floor)", into = c("address", "unit"))
#>           address    unit
#> 1 123 Main Street  Unit A
#> 2 456 Main Street   Apt 3
#> 3 789 Main Street Floor 2
```

Comment: This does work, thank you. I accepted this answer instead of Karthik S's answer because this formulation is truer to the question in that it specifies the delimiters rather than using the street address.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

Using base R:

```
gsub('(\\d+\\sMain Street\\s)(.*)','\\2',df$ADDRESS)
[1] "Unit A"  "Apt 3"   "Floor 2"
```

Using dplyr and stringr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(UNIT = str_extract(ADDRESS, '(?<=Main Street ).*'))
                  ADDRESS    UNIT
1  123 Main Street Unit A  Unit A
2   456 Main Street Apt 3   Apt 3
3 789 Main Street Floor 2 Floor 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be helpful in base R:

```
df$UNIT <- trimws(regmatches(df$ADDRESS, regexpr("\\d+\\s+Main\\s+Street\\K(.*)", df$ADDRESS, perl = TRUE)))

                  ADDRESS    UNIT
1  123 Main Street Unit A  Unit A
2   456 Main Street Apt 3   Apt 3
3 789 Main Street Floor 2 Floor 2
```